# Is it unethical of me to give an answer to a poorly asked question for the easy reputation?

Tags: discussion, ethics

I'll often see some poorly phrased questions that either supply no code or are unclear, but I'll still give them a viable answer and receive the 25+ reputations points. Is this unethical? Should I refrain from helping them for looking for free coding/automation help?

This isn't a question about waiting for clarity to be made, because in these cases the poster is brand new and is just looking for a fast free solution. Also, the question isn't always unclear. Sometimes it's very clear, but they're looking for someone to do all the work. Please see the link below for an example.

[Matching Sort Code and Account Numbers in two worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569382/matching-sort-code-and-account-numbers-in-two-worksheets/44571674?noredirect=1#comment76132620_44571674)

Comment: Ethics aside, answering bad questions only invites them to keep asking bad questions.  So by answering these types of questions, you are contributing to the question quality problem on SO.

Comment: Is it bad manners to walk through spilled milk and track it all over the floor when you know people are coming to clean it up? Either help clean it up if you have time or leave it alone and don't make it worse.

Comment: Two additional things: 1) You're not helping the OP in the long term by trapping them with a question that's a down vote magnet. That just helps them get question banned faster. 2) Answering an unclear question when you know it's unclear is also risky: If you're wrong about what the OP actually meant you're inviting down votes, especially if they later edit their answer to clarify.

Comment: Its good to keep in mind what this site is for. You're not answering to help the OP, you're answering so other people can benefit from the answer too. But on poorly asked questions your work will very likely be wasted as people will not find your answer.

Comment: "Ethicality" is merely one of many dimensions, and probably the least important one, as well as being the hardest to define. It's more interesting to ask is answering such questions worth your time, does it contribute to the site long-term, etc. Your question is not a dup, but it is certainly a matter of opinion.

Comment: @psubsee2003 How can you say "ethics aside", when the entire question is about ethics?

Comment: @torazaburo which is why my response is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes.  Please, don't do this.

If the question is *poor* - that is, it's easily seen as off topic to any other observer, then no one really benefits from it being around, and answers to it will only reinforce in the OPs mind that this is somehow okay to do.  It's even worse if they're only looking for coding help; not only have you given the OP the impression that it's fine to ask these sorts of questions, you've undersold yourself as a consultant.

I would not encourage you to answer easy questions just for quick reputation.  There are more constructive ways to get your reputation up.

Comment: Think of reputation in the everyday sense of the word. Do you want to be known for sharing knowledge, or do you simply want to be known for doing other people's work for them? Do you want to be known for answering good questions, or bad ones?

Comment: @snb:  I'm not sure why my low-expertise-required answers are garnering such flak from you.  It's not the case that the questions I answered were poor, either; it's just the case that the answers I gave were *good*.  I realize I'm adding another layer of paint to the bikeshed, but that's preferable to adding a layer of *anything* to a pile of garbage.

Comment: @snb:  I would hope that this could be inferred...the ideal "don't answer poor questions for easy rep" would likely be translated to "answer questions which aren't poor for rep".

Comment: You answered a different question than what was asked. The question was whether doing this was **ethical**, not whether "anyone benefits".

Answer (score 13):

It depends on how bad the question is.  If the question deserves closure (too broad, no MCVE), then flag it for closure and don't answer.

However, if it's just "poorly asked" and otherwise on-topic, you should instead edit the question.  Then you can provide an answer to the presentable, on-topic question.  There's even a set of badges ([Explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer), [Refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner), [Illuminator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator)) to reward this behavior  of editing the question and providing a useful answer.