# Should I participate in answering questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm still an undergraduate student, but I have some experience in a few programming languages. I know that I can answer a lot of the easy questions from other new guys and gals, but should I? Being new to it, I would likely be a little slower and give the second or third answer to an easy question by the time I post it. This, in turn, would cause me to be discouraged in bothering to post what I have, when I can see that the other earlier answers are probably better than what I'm going to put out in a minute.

When would it be appropriate to bother trying to answer?

Comment: Questions trivially answered by simple research *don't belong on the site at all*.

Comment: If you know how to answer a question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/) then you're golden.  If you don't then you can always figure it out, everybody can.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and say that you don't want me to answer questions.

Comment: Most of the easiest-to-answer questions have already been asked and usually already answered. Before answering, please search for the duplicate question and flag the question as such.

Answer (score 7):

> When would it be appropriate to bother trying to answer?

[When it isn't a poor question that isn't fixable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350770/is-it-unethical-of-me-to-give-an-answer-to-a-poorly-asked-question-for-the-easy) and when your answer would be:

1. Useful
2. Unique

You say that

> ...other earlier answers are probably better than what I'm going to put out...

But better how? A better explanation of why the answer works? A better explanation of what the OP did wrong? More code? Less code? If you have something useful to add that hasn't been posted yet, you can post it.

If you'd rather seek out questions without answers there are [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to help you do that:

[All open unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano)

[All open unanswered questions at least 24hrs old with a score of at least 0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+created%3A..1d+score%3A0..)

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem here is one that you aren't really aware of with regards to your question. Yes, please by all means, answer questions!

*However*, please also abide by the site rules of answering questions which are [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well as [reasonably scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

The implication that your question here presents to some users is that you will answer questions which are not reasonably scoped, which are not on topic, and that is the underlying reason for the sentiment you encountered.

Please, answer on-topic posts, but also keep in mind many members of the Stack Overflow community spend countless hours attempting to ensure that the quality of the site is intact by removing questions which are off topic or not reasonably scoped.

Comment: Duplicates is a big thing too. We don't want to be answering duplicates of duplicates of duplicates of duplicates... etc.

Comment: I agree, but to note it does remark about duplicates in the on topic link, the page states "*Please [look around](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to see if your question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)*."

Comment: What percentage of people reading this post do you figure will actually visit that link? Hell, I figure that the vast majority of people using this site will never visit that page... ever.

Comment: I guess it just depends on if they want to get question banned or not. Being a part of the community means understanding the status quo, and the help pages offer that. Meta offers a way to challenge that. If users never, *ever* visit those pages then they are really doing a disservice to themselves as it will be hard for them to integrate with the community here.

Comment: No argument from me.

Answer (score 3):

If you start out by answering general beginner questions in  a high-traffic tag like, for instance, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) you are *probably* going to have a bad time. There are surprisingly few good quality Java questions left that don't have a duplicate and the ones that are good quality will get snapped up by the [fastest guns in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

One option to consider is to begin answering in a niche, low-traffic tag before graduating to high-traffic tags. Rather than, say, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) is there a Java or Python library or API you have been using at university for which you have gathered some knowledge?

If there is, you could try monitoring that tag for a while to see the sorts of answers that are well-received. You can then look at the most highly rated questions to get exposed to the existing body of knowledge present on StackOverflow. Then when you do eventually answer in that tag, you will be able to make a high-quality contribution that builds on the existing knowledge base.

Answer (score -11):

My immediate thought is that I *should* answer easy questions. The reason, what I believe, is obvious:

Users here that know the ins-and-outs of any given programming language can focus more on high quality answers to other moderately more difficult questions. They still get to grow their reputation while assisting others who may actually rely on them to achieve their research goals or work deadlines. This way, us new users can continue to answer the constant stream of other new users so that we can gain the knowledge of how to operate in this website. Things like protocol and "quality" of answers can be worked out later, similar to a person in the gym how other long-time gym users can give quick comments for suggestions. Yes, we're going to suck at it now, but through the constructive criticism of more experienced users, we can learn what works and what doesn't. This will likely also encourage new answerers to keep trying to learn more.

Comment: If you're writing your answer at the same time as everybody else on a new question, go for it. If, however you find an old question with existing answers, do take time to read those first and answer if you feel you can add something they didn't cover but there's no real point in adding answers if you can't do that.

Comment: "Things like protocol and 'quality' of answers can be worked out later," ... no, this is not how things work.  If you post too many answers of poor quality (and/or questions), you are effectively polluting the site and will probably run into some bans.  Or at least suffer lots of reputation drop.  You actually can learn quite a lot about how the site works just by lurking. Bottom line, if you can post quality content, go for it; if not, don't. Do note that "quality" does not necessarily imply "advanced."

Comment: You make a comparison to a gym; a gym is a social gathering where social interaction is encouraged. Stack Overflow, the Q&A section of it at least, absolutely is not. Please: read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before you go down the path of a very sour experience. If you feel brave and have plenty of time to spare, try giving this meta question and most of its answers a read: [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)